# X509 custom extensions - how do you set them?

Tags: c#, x509, x509certificate2

Despite doing a extensive search, I cannot find any examples of setting custom extensions (the `CustomExtensions` property) on a X509 (v3) certificate.

If I want to generate a new certificate (based on an existing CA certificate already installed on the machine), how can I add custom extensions to it? I am looking to carry some extra custom information around in the certificate for later inspection. Can this be done programmatically or by using makecert? Or can these extensions only be set by writing a [custom policy module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387704%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that is invoked when the certificate is generated? Can this even be achieved by using the regular `X509Certificate` or `X509Certificate2` classes from the .Net framework?

I have found code to inspect the custom extensions, but none to set it.

Comment: [tag:custom-extensions] is a bit ... *generic*.  Can you find something better?

Comment: Note that I will be offering a minimum 200 bounty on this when it becomes eligible. Suggestions of libraries etc. are welcome provided they answer the question and you can show a working sample.

Comment: @Charles - done. It was a new tag, now I've refined it a bit.

Comment: Many thanks.  You may wish to find other questions to which it could apply.  New tags hate being stuck with only one question...

Comment: @slugster: Have you checked this library? http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Answer (score 1):

Whatever existing certificate you have, it's "sealed" by signing. Changing their contents invalidates the signature and consequently the certificate. That is why you couldn't find any information about what you want to do.

What can confuse you is custom properties of the certificate when you view it via Certificate Management snap-in in MMC or when browsing certificates in Internet Explolrer. Such properties are not stored in the certificate - they are kept by CryptoAPI separately, not "embedded" into the certificate.

For self-signed certificates for which you have a private key you can re-create the certificate and have custom extensions added to it, but this is a rare case. I am not sure that .NET Framework lets you work with custom extensions, but our SecureBlackbox does.

Comment: I am looking to embed some customer specific information in the certificate at the moment it is generated (it won't be changed after that, it is intended that the information can be examined when the certificate is used/presented) - but I have not found clear instructions on how to do that. Can it only be done via a certificate template? Can that template be generated or modified on the fly before creating the certificate?

Comment: @slugster maybe I have misunderstood your question in "generate a new certificate (based on an existing certificate already installed on the machine)" part. I don't know how to generate certificates with custom extensions using .NET classes and if it's really possible.